# I don't know why I can't use bitmapTransform

Tags: android, android-glide

For using `bitmapTransform`, I added 2 compile in dependencies.

As you can see below, glide and glide-transformations are added successfully.

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
compile 'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.2.0'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.0.0'
compile 'jp.wasabeef:glide-transformations:2.0.2'
```

But I can't use `bitmapTransform` method at `Glide.with(this).load(url)`.?

bitmapTransform method is not shown above.

Answer (score 0):

I solved problem.

I modified compile version from glide:4.0.0 to glide:3.7.0.

Then, I can use bitmapTransform.